# Resetting the Zoom on a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, uipageviewcontroller

I am building up a simple application that is made up of a `UITableViewController` with languages and when a specific cell is clicked, a `UIPageViewController` is brought up to represent the images for that selected language. The user can scroll through the images and everything works as desired. The next step was to build a zooming capability into the `UIPageViewController` so the user could zoom into the images with a pinch gesture.

I have achieved this with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.leafletImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"3facts-chinese-page1.jpg"], [[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"3facts-chinese-page2.jpg"], [[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"3facts-chinese-page3.jpg"], [[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"3facts-chinese-page4.jpg"], [[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"3facts-chinese-page5.jpg"], [[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"3facts-chinese-page6.jpg"], nil];

    // Lots of code for the building up of the UIPageViewController

LeafletImageSizeViewController *imageViewController = [[LeafletImageSizeViewController alloc] init];
imageViewController.model = [_modelArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:imageViewController];

[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:nil];


    // Gesture
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchDetected:)]; 
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
    pinchRecognizer.delegate=self;

}
```

The class creating the image and the size is:

```
- (void)useThreeFactsSize
CGRect insetFrame;
        insetFrame = CGRectMake(310, 70, self.view.frame.size.width-615, self.view.frame.size.height-85);
_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:insetFrame];
[_imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_model.imageName]];
[[self view] addSubview:_imageView];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

}

The pinchDetection method is:

```
-(void)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchRecognizer
{
    CGFloat scale = pinchRecognizer.scale;
    self.pageViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.pageViewController.view.transform, scale, scale);
    pinchRecognizer.scale = 1.0;
}
```

Now, I can zoom into the images of the `UIPageViewController` without any issues and it works really well.

What I want to do however is two things:

1. Not allow the image to be zoomed out beyond the original scale
2. Create a double tap gesture to bring the image back to it's original scale

With feature 1, the user can zoom into the image, but also completely zoom out of the image which shrinks the image and the `UIPageViewController` `pageIndicators`. There's no reason the user should be able to zoom out of the image, so I'd like to allow the user to zoom in to any scale, but not to zoom out beyond what the original size of the image on screen in the `UIPageViewController`.

With feature 2, I'd like to implement a gesture to double tap the screen and for the zoomed image to go back to it's original scale (like the Photos.app).

**Update**

With reference to the answer, I have updated the question to reflect how I'm going about doing the images. With point 2 and the double tap gesture, the following code almost works:

```
- (void)scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Double Tap");
    self.pageViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

}
```

What it's currently doing is if I zoom in with a pinch and pan around, and then double tap, it centres the image to the point of where I tapped, so sometimes the borders are being shown, etc, rather than making the image centre to where it's supposed to be.

For point 1:

```
if (pinchRecognizer.scale > 1) {


    CGFloat scale = pinchRecognizer.scale;
    self.pageViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.pageViewController.view.transform, scale, scale);
    pinchRecognizer.scale = 1.0;


}
```

If I have self.imageview, it doesn't work because it's nil and even if I make a call to the class setting the size, it's nil as well.

I suspect I have a number of things wrong with my code!

For reference, I have panning working with:

```
- (void)panGestureDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
        [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformTranslate(recognizer.view.transform, translation.x, translation.y)];
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view];
    }
    else if(state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        UIView *imageView = recognizer.view;
        UIView *container = imageView.superview;

        CGFloat targetX = CGRectGetMinX(imageView.frame);
        CGFloat targetY = CGRectGetMinY(imageView.frame);


        if(targetX>0){
//                        targetX = 0;
        }else if(CGRectGetMaxX(imageView.frame)<CGRectGetWidth(container.bounds)){
            targetX = CGRectGetWidth(container.bounds)-CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame);
        }

        if(targetY>0){
//                        targetY = 0;
        }else if(CGRectGetMaxY(imageView.frame)<CGRectGetHeight(container.bounds)){
//                        targetY = CGRectGetHeight(container.bounds)-CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame);
        }


//        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(targetX, targetY, CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame));

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(targetX, targetY, CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame));
        }];
    }
}
```

That's working very well at the moment, but there's definitely a conflict with everything else.

I'd really appreciate any guidance in the right direction on this.

Answer (score 0):

1.) To not allow the image to be zoomed out beyond it's original scale you first just need to check if the scale you're about to set it to is greater than 1 or not. If it's less than one, you don't want to rescale your image as that would mean it gets smaller. So...

```
    @IBAction func doPinch(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.scale > 1 {
        let transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sender.scale, sender.scale)

        imageView.transform = transform
    }
}
```

2.) You seem to be changing the view's frame to try and change it's scale, but you never adjusted the view's frame yourself in the first place. You're adjusting the view's `transform`. That means in order to return it to it's original size you must remove whatever transform you put on it. To do this you put it back to it's identity. So...

```
@IBAction func doDoubleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
}
```

My code samples are in Swift but you should be able to adjust it to Objective-C yourself. Also, you seem to be adjusting the transform/scale of the entire page view itself. I would suggest you change the scale of only the image view. That makes more sense as that's actually what you're trying to zoom into.

Comment: Dear @Sam - many thanks for your work on this and I really appreciate it! So a couple of things to note - the second point almost works perfectly but it's probably a reflection on the first point. Since writing this question, I have slightly changed my model in the sense that the UIImageView is actually being called from another class where I'm setting the size, etc. So I load up the UIPageViewController with a NSArray of UIImages and another class is getting the size, so if I use self.imageView in this case for the first point, that's nil. I've updated the question with everything that's

Comment: Going on, but I suspect things are a real mess here with the way I'm doing things!

Comment: Hi @Sam - So I figured the only issues I'm having now are preventing zooming out (if I follow the structure with checking the scale - it doesn't allow me to zoom out of the image, but if I zoom in, it doesn't allow me to zoom out as well. Secondly, the double tap gesture is making the UIPageViewController centre to where I tapped it, so if I'm panning around, it will centre the tap and obscure the rest of the image.